Controller destroyed with offAllNamed
The situation is as follows:
Home->A->B->C.
What I want to do is to remove everything and navigate to B in its initial state. To do this, I run offAllNamed(B, route.settings.name == Home).
The problem is that the controller of B has been destroyed and not rebuilt. The same happens with offNamedUntil
Any solution?
